# In Greasemonkey/javascript, how can I handle new elements added to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, greasemonkey

I have written a Greasemonkey script which manipulates the contents of certain elements with the following selector:

```
$("span.relativetime").each(function() { $(this).html("TEST"); });
```

However, sometimes matching elements are added to the page through AJAX, and I don't know how to handle those new elements.  I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$("span.relativetime").live(function() { $(this).html("TEST"); });
```

The [documentation for jQuery live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) says that it wants an event (like "click").  But I don't have any event, I just want to know when something matching my selector has been created, and then I want to modify it.

**Background**: I am encountering this problem with a Greasemonkey script to display StackOverflow's relative timestamps as absolute local timestamps, which [you can find on meta-SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12635/greasemonkey-script-to-display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time).  The problem is when you click "show all comments", the new comments are added by AJAX, and I don't know how to find and replace the timestamps in those scripts.

Answer (score 0):

With StackOverflow's setup I find it annoying to handle stuff after the comments. What I've done is put a bind on the Add/Remove comments button that uses setTimeout to wait for the elements to be created, and then modify them.

Comment: Is there no general-purpose way of doing this though, regardless of what site you're on?  It seems like something that would be needed fairly frequently.

Comment: StackOverflow 'creates' the comments. I don't see many sites that do that. They mostly just 'show' them. Instead SO grabs them via AJAX

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try (although I'm not sure if it would work) is to cache your selection in some global variable like so:

```
var $relativetime = $("span.relativetime");
```

Then you would have your .each function:

```
$relativetime.each(function() { $(this).html("TEST"); });
```

After your new elements were added to the DOM, you could reselect append to your cached object:

```
$relativetime.append("<my html>"); //or
$("<my html>").appendto($relativetime);
```

(P.s. `.html()` is for setting html. To set text, use `.text()`